# How do I test sshguard on debian?

Tags: ssh

I want to replace fail2ban with sshguard because it uses less resources. I installed sshguard via apt-get and it seems to be running on my debian wheezy server:

```
# /etc/init.d/sshguard status
sshguard is running.
```

How do I check if it really works?

I tried to log in with a false password, fail2ban banned me after 6 wrong login attempts for some minutes. but now with only sshguard running I get never banned.

What is the default settings on a fresh install? The [documentation](http://www.sshguard.net/docs/) is quite overwhelming and doesn't show a short description how it works

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods:

1. see output of   **iptables -nvL sshguard**
2. see  output of  **journalctl -afb -p info SYSLOG_FACILITY=4 SYSLOG_FACILITY=10**
3. see the log  **/var/log/syslog**

Comment: I get `iptables/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported` and `iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): chain `sshguard' in table `filter' is incompatible, use 'nft' tool.`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @rubo77  the problem is your iptables, see this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/988412/iptables-1-8-2-failed-to-initialize-nft-protocol-not-supported